# Teradata SQL - Grouping Observations Close In Time Together?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table that has line item transactions by account, date, and time (two separate fields) but there is not a unique identifier for each individual transaction.  I want to take a best guess at this by grouping line items that are done around the same time, say within an hour of each other to be conservative.  My initial thought was extract the hour from the time field and use that but there are instances where a transaction can cross an hour.  For example, line 1 was done at 8:57 AM and line 2 was done at 9:01 AM.  I would want these to be grouped together but just using the hour would not accomplish that.

Any thoughts?  Example data is provided below with an added field showing if I would group them together or not.

```
Account | Date   | Time      | Group
A       | 1/1/16 | 8:57:00   | 1
A       | 1/1/16 | 9:01:00   | 1
A       | 1/1/16 | 9:16:00   | 1
A       | 1/1/16 | 12:15:00  | 2
A       | 1/1/16 | 12:32:00  | 2
B       | 1/2/16 | 7:23:00   | 3
B       | 1/2/16 | 7:24:00   | 3
B       | 1/3/16 | 9:18:00   | 4
B       | 1/3/16 | 11:24:00  | 5
```

Comment: are date and time separate columns in the table?

Comment: Yes, they are separate columns

Comment: You need to define the boundaries by which you will round up to the next hour. From there it is a combination of using the `EXTRACT(HOUR FROM {Time})` and `EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM {Time})` in a `CASE` statement with some logic to address rounding up to Midnight and advancing to the the next `DAY`.

Comment: How about 8:00/8:30/9:00/9:30? Would they all go into the same group?

Answer (score 0):

```
select      "Account"
           ,"Date"
           ,"Time"
           ,count (is_new_group) over (partition by "Account" order by ts rows unbounded preceding) + 1     as "Group"


from       (select      "Account"
                       ,"Date"
                       ,"Time"
                       ,cast ("Date" as timestamp) + (("Time" - time '00:00:00') hour to second)                                                                        as ts 
                       ,case when ts > min (ts) over (partition by "Account" order by ts rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) + interval '1' hour then 'Y' end     as is_new_group

            from        t
            )
            t
;
```

Comment: @user1723699, does it answer your question?